# What is the HTC account you sync on the One X?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-one-x

I just got my HTC One X and was just going through the registration process of the HTC Account in the 'Accounts & Sync' settings, when someone asked me to show them something. Without thinking I pressed back and now when I try and register again, I'm told I can't as it exists.

I'd like to know, is there a matching web service for this which I can use to get my password back? What account is it? I had assumed it was for HTCSense.com but it doesn't seem to be.

Anyone have any idea's please? Otherwise I'll just have to try and login to it repeatedly which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Looks like the phone is new and not setup much, so why don't you factory reset it? Or Deleting data from Account and Sync app or similar app might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have rebooted my phone and when I tried again it let me register. The account is linked to htcsense.com which seems odd as there is a message there saying that it's closing down its services!